# ExtJS - Where to put new plugins?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In ExtJS 6.2 modern application directory structure, where should I put new plugins?

In ExJS the `PagingToolbar` plugin has this definition `Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar`, if I create a Grid plugin should I put it in `APP/grid/plugin/MyPlugin`?

Also, do I have to import the plugin into the system somehow before use?

Comment: forgot to ask: do you use a workspace?

Comment: @Dinkheller No we currently don't use workspaces.

Comment: Ok. Because otherwise it would be workspace/packages/local/CorePackage/src/plugins/grid/plugin/MyPlugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: Where to put the plugin

If your plugin extends the pagingtoolbar plugin or if it fits logically into the same space ...

```
workspace/apps/AppName/app/src/grid/plugin/MyPlugin
```

**Question 2**: Import the plugin

You do not need to import the plugin if you added all classes within either file

- app.js
- app/Application.js

using the requires

```
requires: ['Myapp.*']
```

If not, you have to require the plugin in the class you use it.

```
requires: ['Myapp.src.grid.plugin.MyPlugin']
```

**Be careful**

It works without requires in development build, but not in production build.